# QXcbConnection: XCB error: 2 Qt installer Docker

Tags: qt, docker, qt-creator

I trying to setup a docker image with Qt Creator.
I am following the instructions in https://nicroland.wordpress.com/2015/12/06/running-qtcreator-in-docker/

But when running the docker image with the installer I get get a "blank black" dialogue, and a error message scrolling in the terminal.

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
[134] Warning: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 2 (BadValue), sequence: 458,resource id: 820, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
```

When closing the dialogue it does show the normal widget like dialogue that ask "do you want to close the installer application"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the solution:
when you call your QDialog form in your code you are probably doing :

```
form * myform = new form(this);
myform->exec();
```

i resolved the issue by deleting the pointer:

add :

```
delete myform
```

I hope this helps !
good day